# Linking to control panel in C# (Run advertised programs and Configuration Manager)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to link to the control panel from within a C# application.  I am coding in visual studio and trying to find a way to make a link to those two areas in the control panel.

I have been using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() but I can't seem to find a way to actually link my way to anywhere inside of the control panel except for a select few places where applets are already defined,  such as printers and color.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to come upon this solution.

Comment: What do you mean "link to control panel" do you want the control panel to be displayed from inside your program or do you want a new control panel window to be opened when you click a button inside your program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this works for me:

```
var cplPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "control.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cplPath, "/name Microsoft.ProgramsAndFeatures");
```

You can also specify a page of the control panelitem. Check out [Executing Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Canonical Names of Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: However, this works "as of Windows Vista", it does not work in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to launch a control panel window the command is

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control");
```

If you want to launch the individual items in the control panel, you need to know it's filename (check the `Windows\System32` or `Windows\SYSWOW64` for the files, they end in `.cpl`) you can then launch it like this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control", "powercfg.cpl");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type "Start Control" or "Control" into Command Prompt it will open Control Panel.

Therefore I would run a Process and run it.
This Code (Bellow) worked perfectly for me:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}

    #region Variables
    Process p;
    #endregion Variables

    [...]

    void myMethod()
    {
            try
            {
                p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.Start();

                p.StandardInput.WriteLine("start control"); 
                p.StandardInput.Flush();
                p.StandardInput.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```